# MongoDB aggregate - Set and condition $gt,$lte not working

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have 2 collections

1st users and 2nd shifts

When I am writing a query like below with lookup and unwind expressions.

```js
results.users = await model.aggregate([
  {
    $match: filter,
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "shifts",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "employeeId",
      as: "shifts",
    },
  },
  {
  $set: {
    shifts: {
      $filter: {
        input: "$shifts",
         cond: [
           {
             $and: [
               {
                 $gte: [
                   "$$this.date",
                   new Date("2022-10-01"),
                 ],
               },
               {
                 $lte: [
                   "$$this.date",
                   new Date("2022-10-05"),
                 ],
               },
             ],
           },
         ],
      },
    },
  },
},
]);
```

```js
[
  {
    _id: "60dd781c4524e6c116e2336d",
    workerFirstName: "MADASWAMY",
    workerSurname: "KARUPPASWAMY",
    workerId: "1002",
    shifts:[]
  },
  {
    _id: "60dd781d4524e6c116e234d4",
    workerFirstName: "AMIT",
    workerSurname: "SHAH",
    workerId: "1001",
    shifts:[]
  },
  {
    _id: "60dd781d4524e6c116e23642",
    workerFirstName: "DEVELOPER",
    workerSurname: "DEVELOPER",
    workerId: "7738",
    shifts: [
      {
      _id: "634d8d3ce596dd34c9532d5d",
      month: "October",
      workerId: "7738",
      date: "2022-10-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    },
    {
      _id: "634d8d3ce596dd34c9532d5d",
      month: "October",
      workerId: "7738",
      date: "2022-10-02T00:00:00.000Z",
    },
    {
      _id: "634d8d3ce596dd34c9532d5d",
      month: "October",
      workerId: "7738",
      date: "2022-10-03T00:00:00.000Z",
    },
{
      _id: "634d8d3ce596dd34c9532d5d",
      month: "October",
      workerId: "7738",
      date: "2022-10-04T00:00:00.000Z",
    },
{
      _id: "634d8d3ce596dd34c9532d5d",
      month: "October",
      workerId: "7738",
      date: "2022-10-05T00:00:00.000Z",
    },
{
      _id: "634d8d3ce596dd34c9532d5d",
      month: "October",
      workerId: "7738",
      date: "2022-10-06T00:00:00.000Z",
    },
    ....
  ],
  },
]
```

As you can see I am getting, the list of Data.
but I want only specific data between the date range given
Ex : - The date range is from 1 to 5th Oct so I want only that much data but I am getting all data.

Comment: If you remove the last `$unwind` step, you'll get the data you want

Comment: @nimrodserok tried but that condition is not working inside set

Answer (score 0):

i tried doing this and it worked for me

```js
{
      $set: {
        attendances: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$attendances",
            cond: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $gte: ["$$this.Date", new Date(fromDate)],
                },
                {
                  $lte: ["$$this.Date", new Date(toDate)],
                },
                {
                  $eq: ["$$this.createdAs", dataType],
                },
                {
                  $eq: ["$$this.status", true],
                },
                {
                  $eq: ["$$this.workerType", workerType],
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
```

Just removed the array brackets from the condition